# How to take position mouse up after mouse down and compare them? With addEventListener JS

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have array of slides

```
sliderItem.forEach((slide, index) => {
    slide.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) =>{
        touchStart(e)
    })
    slide.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) =>{ 
        touchEND(e)
    })
 })
```

and i have function for take position clientX

```
function getPositionX(e){
  return e.type.includes('mouse') ? e.pageX : e.touches[0].clientX
}
```

and 2 functions for take positions

```
function touchStart(e) {
     const startPos = getPositionX(e)
}
function touchEnd(e) {
     const endPos = getPositionX(e)
}
```

It take the same positions for start and for end, i need to take at first position start, after take position of end and then compare them to understand for which way to turn the slides

Comment: `const startPos =` you need to move this to the outer *scope* of `touchStart`,  eg `var startPos; function touchStart(e) { startPos = getPositionX` then in endPos, you can reference startPos

Comment: @freedomn-m, sorry, may be i don't understand you, but in touchEnd i can't work with startPos, because i can see it only in function touchStart

Comment: Hence the "move startPos to the outer scope" and an example of how to do this.

Comment: Something like: https://jsfiddle.net/c9yv4q03/

Comment: @freedomn-m, thank u so much fo example on fiddle, it's worked for me, brilliant